# Number of ways to write integers in balanced binary

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Imagine a method of writing integers which is similar to [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary), except as you write more digits, their value increases by a factor of 2, not 3. For the remainder of the post, I will call this system  "balanced binary". For example: (with T representing -1)

1T11 $= 1*2^0 + 1*2^1 - 1*2^2 + 1*2^3 = 7$

10T $= -1*2^0 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^2 = 3$

Obviously, there is more than one way to represent each integer in this system, as an n-digit number can range from $-2^{n+1}+1$ to $2^{n+1}-1$, which contains roughly $2^{n+2}$ numbers, and the n-digit balanced binary string has n ternary digits, which can represent $3^{n}$ numbers, clearly more as n grows.

If given a string in balanced binary, you can apply 2 transformations to the string which do not change its value. These are:

1T <=> 01

T1 <=> 0T

For example:

1T11 $= 7$

10T1 $= 1*2^0 - 1*2^1 +0*2^2 + 1*2^3 = 7$

These represent the fact that $2-1=0+1$, and $1-2=0-1$, respectively.

By applying these transformations to eliminate all T's, all positive numbers written in balanced binary can be converted to their standard binary representations. For negative numbers, the same can be done by eliminating all 1's, then swapping every T with a 1 and adding a negative sign.

What I would like to know is: how can I compute a function which, given an integer and a string length, outputs the number of ways the integer can be written in a balanced binary string of the given length, and, optionally, a list of the representations.

Comment: [Just a comment for now] I'd try listing out the first few cases for counting numbers $1$ to $5$ or so, then see if you can spot an inductive (or recursive) proof of a conjectured formula.

Comment: Is it binary if it uses three symbols to represent numbers? By contrast, balanced ternary uses the same number ($3$) of symbols as regular ternary.

Comment: I'm mostly calling it binary because the value of digits increases in powers of 2. If you can think of a better name I'll edit the post to replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the given length of the balanced binary representation. 
Let $x$ be an integer, such that $0\le x \le 2^n-1$.  
Let $b(0),b(1),\dots,b(n-1)$ be the binary digits $x$, so each $b(i)\in \{0,1\}$, and $$x=2^{n-1}b({n-1}) + \dots + 2^0b(0).$$

> **Defintion:** A *noncrossing 0-1 matching* for $x$ is a list of integers $[m_1,\dots,m_{2k}]$ of even length, such that
>
> - $n - 1 \ge m_1> m_2> \dots > m_{2k} \ge 0$.
> - For all $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, $b(m_{2i-1})=0$ and $b(m_{2i})=1$.

In words, we find all ways to select a set of disjoint contiguous subsequences of the list $[b(n-1),\dots,b(0)]$, where each subsequence begins with a zero and ends with a one.

Each noncrossing 0-1 matching determines a representation of $x$ of length $n$ in balanced binary, as follows. For $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, and each interval of digits of the form
$$
[b(m_{2i-1}),b(m_{2i-1}-1),\dots,b(m_{2i})], \qquad b(m_{2i-1})=0,\quad b(m_{2i})=1,
$$
we will modify the digits in this interval as follows. We make replacements of the form `01 -> 1T` and `T1 -> 0T` until the only remaining `1` in this block of digits occurs on the left. What remains will be a block starting with $1$, where the rest is made of `0` and `T`, such that the last digit is `T`.

For example, with $n=5$ and $x=00101_2=5$, here are the noncrossing 0-1 matchings, and the resulting balanced binary representations.

| Noncrossing 0-1 matching | Balanced binary rep of 5 |
| --- | --- |
| $\text{empty list}$ | `00101` |
| $[1, 0]$ | `0011T` |
| $[3, 2]$ | `01T01` |
| $[3,2,1,0]$ | `01T1T` |
| $[3,0]$ | `010TT` |
| $[4,2]$ | `1TT01` |
| $[4,2,1,0]$ | `1TT1T` |
| $[4,0]$ | `1T0TT` |

> **Claim:** Every balanced binary representation for $x$ of length $n$ is generated in a unique way by some non-crossing 0-1 matching for $x$.

*Proof of claim:* Given a balanced binary representation $B$ of $x$,  where the length of $B$ is $n$, we find the corresponding noncrossing 0-1 matching as follows.

1. Find the rightmost instance of `T`; its location is the smallest entry in the non-crossing matching.
2. Find the rightmost instance of `1` which is to the left of the `T` in the previous step; its location is the second smallest entry in the noncrossing matching.
3. Continue capturing intervals like this, where the rightmost digit is a `T`, the leftmost digit is a `1`, and all digits between are `0` or `T`, until all `T`s have been captured in some interval.

This proves that every string is generated. Proof of uniqueness is not too bad, and left to the reader. $\square$

Using the claim, you can imagine a simple backtracking program which enumerates all non-crossing 0-1 matchings of $x$.

Comment: Excellent solution, better than mine in both style and substance - comes with reasoning, and computation should be quadratic in n, at least.

Comment: @Ironfilings No, the computation time is exponential in the worst case. Suppose that $x$ in binary looks like `0101...01`, with $n/2$ copies of $01$. Then there will be $F_{n+1}$ representations. The Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially, so it takes exponential time just to write down all the reps. Perhaps there is a clever way to compute the number of ways without traversing through all of them, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote out the sequences for the numbers 1-15 in excel, like so:
[image: excel table of the sequences for numbers 1-15]

I noticed that the end half of the sequences of length 3 was the same as the sequences of length 2. For example, the number of equivalent sequences of length 2 goes 1,2,1,1, and the number of equivalent sequences of length 3 goes 1,3,2,3,1,2,1,1. 1,2,1,1 appears on the end of both. This inspired me to write this sequence in reverse, and plug it into the OEIS, and I found that it matched (perfectly, if you include sequences of length 0) [OEIS A002487](https://oeis.org/A002487), which is generated like so:

f(0) = 0

f(1) = 1

f(2n) = f(n)

f(2n+1) = f(n) + f(n+1)

With this insight (and blind trust the sequence remains accurate), a solution presents itself.

If $g(x, l)$ is the function I want, and $f(x)$ is defined above, outputting the number of ways to write the number $x$ as a sequence of length $l$:

$g(x, l) = f(2^l-x)$

This is obviously a little unsatisfying, with no real reasoning, but computes the answer.